# php how to create inline button for share message

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Telegram has a bot, it's name is @like. You can create vote with that bot.

[image]

My problem is with share button. How can I share, created voting message so other user can like or dislike it?

@like bot give me blew string for sharing. How can I achieve that in php?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

finally i found how to do that. i'm using [irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk) library for laravel.

so for share a message we can use: `switch_inline_query`

```
 $inlineLayout[][] = Keyboard::inlineButton(['text' => 'forward me to groups', 'switch_inline_query' => 'post_'.$post->id]);
            $keyboard = $this->telegram->replyKeyboardMarkup([
                'inline_keyboard' => $inlineLayout,

            ]);

$response = $this->telegram->sendMessage()
                            ->replyMarkup($keyboard)
                            ->chatId($chatid)
                            ->text("sample Text")
                            ->getResult();
```